# Possible to retrive added records from spotify?

Tags: c#, asp.net, spotify

I've a question about the Spotify API. 
Is't possible to write a function against the Spotify API that retrives all records for a certain country added the last 24 hours?

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you contacted the Spotify developers to ask them?

Comment: Nope, i'm asking you!

Comment: You should contact the developer of the API first. As they will have a much better knowledge about it than most.

Answer (score 0):

No, this functionality isn't available in the API. You can do a search for "tag:new" (like `http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album?q=tag:new`) to get some of the newer stuff, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks iKenndac! Do you know what "new" means in this case?

Comment: "some of the newer stuff" is as accurate as it gets - stuff added fairly recently.